# Org mode: Adding a properties drawer to a capture template?

Tags: org-mode

When I capture an item in org-capture, I have a template which adds "DATE_CAPTURED: %T" to it.

How do I make it so that DATE_CAPTURED is added inside a PROPERTY drawer?

Also, how would I make *any* org-mode-automated property (like DEADLINE, CLOSED, or SCHEDULED) get added to the PROPERTY drawer, instead of directly under the headline?

Comment: `org-mode` relies heavily upon finding the DEADLINE / SCHEDULED / CLOSED directly underneath the main heading when performing searches used to create the `*Org Agenda*` buffer; and other types of searches.  Moving them to a property drawer will break functionality of many built-in features.

Comment: I like to see everything in my capture window while I am editing/creating the entry, so I actually include the property drawers in my template along with certain spacing and line-endings `\n`.  I use the following format for the current date in my DEADLINE and/or SCHEDULED:  `<%<%Y-%m-%d %a>`  You could have an entry that states something like:  `:DATE_CAPTURED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this function and the hook in `init.el`

```lisp
(defun add-property-with-date-captured ()
  "Add DATE_CAPTURED property to the current item."
  (interactive)
  (org-set-property "DATE_CAPTURED" (format-time-string "%F")))

(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook 'add-property-with-date-captured)
```

which will add to the current heading in your capture buffer property `DATE_CAPTURED` with the date in ISO 8601 format when you'll end the capturing (after pressing `C-c C-c` in the capture buffer).  So, you'll see the `DATE_CAPTURED` property in the capture file.

Comment: thx this works well. yet when i have a capture template that already creates a drawer, this will add an additional drawer. is there anyway around that?

Comment: Does it create second `PROPERTIES` drawer?

Comment: yes it does do that.

Comment: Which code do you use to create first (your) drawer into template? You could create question and gave link to.